# What are usual maximum output frequencies on Android audio out?

Tags: android, audio

I wonder if sound pulses of 40kHz or higher can be generated on Android through audio out. Does anyone know if Android devices are capable of generating ultrasound? Do the audio processors support ultrasound?

Note that I'm talking about audio out (left/right) only and not through the speakers.

Answer (score 1):

The end results depends on the hardware and will vary from phone to phone. I've found measurements of headphone jack performance on Samsung Galaxy Note 5, and they show that it can output up to 80 kHz with almost the same level as for the "hearable" audio spectrum:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-5/572012-note-5-headphone-jack-audio-performance-measurements.html

Not sure what you mean by "audio processors" -- DSP?

**UPDATE**:

And for a contrast, here are some measurements of Nexus 7 2013 in 24/96 mode using both its headphones jack and via an external USB DAC:

http://archimago.blogspot.com/2014/04/measurements-nexus-7-to-audioengine-d3.html

If we look at this particular graph in 24/96 mode:

[image: Nexus 7 2013]

The light blue line (measurements done via the headphone jack) abruptly goes down at 20 kHz, which means the onboard DSP deliberately chops any frequencies above it.

So that's exactly what I'm talking about--it's very much device specific and ideally you should test each device you are targeting.

Comment: I'm not sure if my understanding is correct, but did you get 80kHz from the first graph (x-axis)? For other low-/mid-end phones, do they typically support higher than 50kHz?

Comment: Yes, this is what the graph shows, after 50 kHz mark there are 3 more lines each designating 10 more kHz. Though the post says that Note 5 supports audio playback of files with 192 kHz sampling rate, which should reproduce frequencies up to 96 kHz, so maybe the 80 kHz limit on the graph is due to poor setup of the measurement device.     Cheaper devices can limit the output to 20 kHz. I'm updating my answer with a link to Nexus 7 2013 measurements I've found.